# Проблемы с отрисовкой в SDL и ошибка SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, sdl2, segmentation-fault

Здравствуйте! У меня проблема с функцией для вывода объекта в SDL.

Вот в этом коде он выдаёт SIGSEGV:

```
void Window::draw(Object *toDraw)
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(coreRenderer, SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(getRenderer(), toDraw->getSurface()), NULL, NULL);
}
```

Думаю, по названиям функций/переменных всё понятно, если нет, то весь код [ТУТ](http://pastebin.com/y8096tiP)

Очень надеюсь на вас и вашу помощь

Comment: Также подозреваю, что у меня есть утечка памяти, т.к. нужно удалить toDraw

Comment: А что мешает вам пройтись по коду в отладчике и локализовать проблему?

Comment: Ну я не без дела сижу. Я пытаюсь. Однако если-бы получалось, глупых вопросов не писал-бы